# Create distinctive groups for one variable

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to define distinct groups based on one variable. This is a simple question but I couldn't figure it out.

In my dataset I have for each tree a number of unique groups (with value 1 in "dist" variable). I would like to create a new variable, which will assign to each group unique distinctive value.

My data looks like:

```
Tree_ID dist 
1       0    
1       1    
1       1    
1       0    
1       1    
1       0
```

I would like to create a new variable which will assign to distinct groups "dist == 1" unique value (unique_gr).

```
Tree_ID dist unique_gr 
1       0    0
1       1    1
1       1    1
1       0    0
1       1    2
1       0    0
```

I have tried to use "ifelse" function to check for the current row, when "dist == 0" means no group

```
 ifelse(dist == 1, "unique_gr", 0) # checking the current row
```

The main issue is how I can specify unique values in "unique_gr" that are different/increasing (e.g. 1,2,3,4..) for each distinct group?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Check this one out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411653/how-do-i-split-a-vector-into-a-list-of-vectors-when-a-condition-is-met/25411832#25411832

Comment: And this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117904/partition-a-vector-avoiding-a-for-loop#comment79199345_46117904

Comment: Thank you @VincentGuillemot for this suggestion. I think I am on the right track. But how can I add new groups to a new variable (column)?

Comment: Using your second post @VincentGuillemot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117904/partition-a-vector-avoiding-a-for-loop#comment79199345_46117904 I managed to get what I wanted. Thank you. My solution is `df$unique_gr <- (1-cummax(df$dist==0)) + cumsum(df$dist==0) * df$dist`

Comment: I would recommand you to use the solution with `rle`, I think my solution does not really work, I have to correct it

Comment: Thank you for this update. I will try `rle` solution. I have used the solution by @ycw and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution from `tidyverse` and `data.table`. The key is to use `rleid` function.

```
# Create example data frame
dt <- read.table(text = "Tree_ID dist 
1       0    
                 1       1    
                 1       1    
                 1       0    
                 1       1    
                 1       0   ",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  mutate(unique_gr = rleid(dist)) %>%
  mutate(unique_gr = ifelse(dist != 0 & first(dist) == 0, unique_gr/2,
                            ifelse(dist != 0 & first(dist) != 0, (unique_gr + 1)/2, 0)))
dt2
  Tree_ID dist unique_gr
1       1    0         0
2       1    1         1
3       1    1         1
4       1    0         0
5       1    1         2
6       1    0         0
```

Notice that this solution will also work if the beginning of `dist` is not `0`, as the following example shows.

```
# Create example data frame with the beginning of dist is not 0
dt_1 <- read.table(text = "Tree_ID dist 
1       1    
                 1       1    
                 1       1    
                 1       0    
                 1       1    
                 1       0   ",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


dt2_1 <- dt_1 %>%
  mutate(unique_gr = rleid(dist)) %>%
  mutate(unique_gr = ifelse(dist != 0 & first(dist) == 0, unique_gr/2,
                            ifelse(dist != 0 & first(dist) != 0, (unique_gr + 1)/2, 0)))
dt2_1
  Tree_ID dist unique_gr
1       1    1         1
2       1    1         1
3       1    1         1
4       1    0         0
5       1    1         2
6       1    0         0
```

Comment: Thank you @ycw for your solutions. I agree `rleid` function is the key. Also, thank you for suggesting solutions when the beginning is not `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, unique_gr := rleid(dist)*dist, Tree_ID][unique_gr != 0,
                     unique_gr := match(unique_gr, unique(unique_gr))]
#   Tree_ID dist unique_gr
#1:       1    0         0
#2:       1    1         1
#3:       1    1         1
#4:       1    0         0
#5:       1    1         2
#6:       1    0         0
```